# Split command to create file with a number as a filename

Tags: filenames, split

I am using the split command to split a 40GB file. I want the resulting split files to be named using incrementing numbers starting from 1 like 1, 2, 3 . . .

Is this possible ?

I am currently using the command `split --numeric-suffixes=1 -l 2 t5` and getting filenames as follows:

```
x01  x02  x03  x04  x05  x06  x07  x08  x09  x10  x11  x12  x13  x14  x15  x16  x17
```

Comment: The problem with `1 2 3... 10 11...` as opposed to `01 02 03... 10 11` is that they sort (in `ls` output or globs for instance) as `1 10 11 2 3...`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  Which is sad in 21st century! `alias ls="ls -v"` for me

Comment: @Philippos, assuming GNU or busybox ls. See also `*(n)` with `zsh` globs (`cat <1->(n) > t5` to reconstruct `t5`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [GNU `split`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html#split-invocation), yes:

```
split --numeric-suffixes=1
```

will use numeric suffixes, starting from 1. (You still need to specify a prefix if you don’t want the default `x`.)

To obtain filenames which are only numbers, you can specify an empty prefix:

```
split --numeric-suffixes=1 -l 2 t5 ""
```

`split` always uses suffixes of the same length, so the default produces `01`, `02` etc. If you want to avoid leading zeroes, you need to post-process the result (and live with the sub-optimal sorting behaviour):

```
rename 's/^0+//' 0*
```

You also need to ensure that `split`’s suffix length provides enough room for all the files you’ll need; the default, two digits, allows for 99 files if you start from 1. You can specify more digits using `-a`, *e.g.* `-a 3`, `-a 4`, etc.

(`split` stops when it runs out of suffixes, with an error. If you stick to its defaults it will automatically increase the suffix length as necessary, but giving it a start suffix disables this.)

Comment: with you command i am getting things like x01  x02  x03  x04  x05  x06  x07  x08  x09  x10  x11  x12  x13  x14  x15  x16  x17

Comment: I *did* mention you’d have to specify the prefix. Anyway, see my updated answer.

Comment: sorry i didn't pay attention to this